# Undefined symbol "RedisModule_DictNext" when loading my own redis module

Tags: c++, c, redis

I'm following along the [official instructions](https://redis.com/blog/writing-redis-modules/) to create a toy redis module. Unfortunately launching the redis server with my module

```
redis-server --port 9112 --loadmodule /etc/my_module.so
```

fails with

```
Module /etc/my_module.so failed to load: /etc/my_module.so: undefined symbol: RedisModule_DictNext
```

Checking the `redismodule.h` header and the documentation, I observe the `RedisModule_DictNext` is not something I'm supposed to define or tweak. So I'm wondering where my error is.

I've tried compiling my example module as C++ and as C file. Both give the same error.

Comment: What's your version of Redis? You need to have a version larger than 5.0.0 for this api.

Comment: @for_stack I have a 6.0 version